# Flyway: Exclude types from clean

Tags: flyway

I am using the Flyway API (flyway-core 2.0.3) with a PostgreSQL 9.1 database.  The database used by the application has the [isn extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/isn.html) installed, which includes several types such as `ean13`.  Unfortunately, installation of this extension requires superuser privileges and is run by the admins, which results in the ownership of the types it creates belonging to whichever superuser installed the extension.

Because Flyway is run with a non-superuser account (although the account is the database owner), it produces the following error during `clean`:

```
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 29: DROP TYPE IF EXISTS "public"."ean13" CASCADE
```

So, my question is:  Is there a way to use Flyway.clean in databases with unmodifiable types?  Perhaps by excluding all types from the clean operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/100

Please weigh in on the discussion.

Comment: Excellent!  That is the issue indeed.  Sorry to have overlooked it.  Thanks for the help.